# Analog to 3 bit digital converter noise immunity problem

Tags: adc, multiplexer, comparator

This task, which at first glance seemed simple enough, caused my left eyelid to twitch nervously. And despite the habit of sorting out my simple things on my own, here I have to turn to the community.

I want to develop a module for my modular system, which, taking a variable control voltage from 0 to 5V at the input, will convert it into 8 triggers available on 8 outputs. I found a schematics to start with based on comparators that I quickly assembled on a breadboard.

[image]

Naturally, I was faced with the problem of noise in the line, which led to the false triggering of comparators when the input voltage is approaching to the the reference voltage. After reading some technical papers, I managed to solve the problem of hysteresis, and as a result, the comparators began to work as intended, triggering in the interval between the upper threshold and the lower one.

[image]

But after demultiplexing of the 3 input bits into my SN74HC238, which was at hand, I found another problem.

[image]

When I feed the CV input with variable voltage 0-5V rotating my 100k pot CW - there is no problem I see on scope - the gates are perfect.

[image]

But rotating it CCW I see a false triggers that I really do not need. I think that the issue is related to a huge threshold that I had to involve to get rid of noise triggering. But may be there is another problem that I do not see.
Is there any trick or method to avoid these false triggers? Thanks!

[image]

- The yellow signal is Output 1 of the SN74HC238

Comment: I don't know if it is too late to make a major modification to your design, but "current loop" signaling is frequently more immune to noise than (high impedance) voltage signaling. There is a standard current loop design that has signals ranging from 4 mA to 20 mA. 0 mA is reserved to indicate a broken connection. The receiver generally consists of a resistor, to convert the current into voltage and an ADC. It would be simpler than what you have, and more robust. You may not want to start over, but it is a suggestion.

Comment: Another technique I would consider is DTMF (dual tone, multiple frequency), the signaling used by touch-tone phones. DTMF chips are readily available (usually, not sure at the moment) for both encoding and decoding DTMF. It is very robust and fairly simple.

Answer (score 1):

Your design is asynchronous , so without a S&H and  latched analog inputs and binary outputs , commutation glitches will occur, but you can filter the narrow pulses out to prevent this with RC filters choose for RC>2 PW50 of the glitch at 50% amplitude.  The 8:3 rise fall times may be used from the datasheet for worse case or for 1 unit measure and add some margin for voltage  temperature variations.

The easiest is use the appropriate cap <1 nF shunting all 8 outputs or any you need

FWIW, there exists a single IC already to do this for a linear LED bar graph display.

Comment: If GS output of CD4532 yields the gate signal on its inputs change (did not probe it yet) then I may use the CD4042 as latch feeding its Clock In with GS output? But then it should be not gate signal but short trigger I think.